# Estimate IOPS for an Amazon EBS volume using Windows PerfMon

Tags: windows, perfmon, amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs, iops

I'm evaluating moving our aging infrastructure to Amazon's AWS and am trying to estimate costs.  I know our current disk space requirements, bandwidth, and most of the other variables that will affect cost.  The one that's got me stumped is IOPS on EBS volumes.  My thought is to capture performance monitor data from our existing servers (using PolyMon), but I'm not sure which PhysicalDisk metrics match up with Amazon's IOPS count.  My two guesses are Disk Reads/Writes or Average Disk Reads/Writes.

Any thoughts?  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Disk Transfers/sec" is the metric you're looking for. It counts discrete I/O operations, rather than throughput.

Comment: Thanks!  Would disk block size make a difference?  Or should I just make sure that the my EBS volume has the same block size as our current physical servers?

Comment: I/O Ops is I/O Ops for the most part, shouldn't matter.